# Unable to redirect from CreateView

Tags: python, django

I'm new and inexperienced in Django and trying to implement a class based view and completely stuck trying to set the success_url.

I've tried two approaches that I think are closest to being correct based on Google and not sure which one is least broken:

1. success_url = 'letters/home' -> leads to unintended redirection /letters/write/letters/home whereas I want it to go to /letters/home
2. reverse_lazy('letters:home') leads to "Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Here's my code:

**View**

```
from .models import Topic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import WriteLetterForm


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'letters/letter/home.html'


class WriteLetterView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'letters/letter/write_letter.html'
    form_class = WriteLetterForm
    success_url = 'letters/home' # reverse_lazy('letters:home')
    # success_url = 'letters/home'
    # success_url = reverse_lazy('HomeView')


    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.topic = Topic.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        result = super(WriteLetterView,
                       self).form_valid(form)
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        # user = authenticate(username=cd['username'],
        #                    password=cd['password1'])
        # login(self.request, user)

        return result
```

**urls.py within app**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'letters'


urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.HomeView.as_view()),
    path('write/<str:slug>', views.WriteLetterView.as_view()),
]
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Letter
from braces.forms import UserKwargModelFormMixin

class WriteLetterForm(UserKwargModelFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    #letter = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Letter.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Letter
        fields = ['body', 'picture_1', 'picture_2', 'picture_3']


    def create(self):
        obj = super(WriteLetterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.author_id = self.user
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Where have I gone wrong? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.HomeView.as_view(),name="home"),
    path('write/<str:slug>', views.WriteLetterView.as_view()),
]


 success_url = reverse_lazy('letters:home')
```

this would do it, as you havent named the home url, thus it was showing url not found

Comment: Thank you! It works :) It won't let accept yet, but will make sure I do. Have a nice day.